# Dotnet AutoMapper Flat schema to complex hierarchy

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper

I have a database table that is very flat in structure. Well I want to create the resulting query into a more structured and hierarchical format once it is returned to the object in dotnet. To do this I have created several model classes that represents how I want to organize to the returned data. Example

Flat Object

```cs
Public class FlatObject {
   public string key1 {get; set;}
   public string key2 {get; set;}
   public string key3 {get; set;}
   public string key4 {get; set;}
}
```

Result Object

```cs
public class ResultObject {
   public Category1 category1 {get;set;}
   public Category2 category2 {get;set;}
   public Category3 category3 {get;set;}
}
```

CategoryExample

```cs
public class Category1 {
   public SubCategory1 sCategory1 {get;set;}
}
```

Subcategory

```cs
public class SubCategory1 {
   public string key1 {get;set;}
}
```

You'll notice there are some deep object in this hierarchy and I'm trying to map the keys from the falt object to these deeply nested object. I have tried AutoMapper, but I'm struggling with mapping this deep of an object. Any insight on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Reasearch https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html and https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html.

Comment: Following this has me feeling like I'm going to be mapping individual properties to their deeper match in the destination object. It's simpler when you have an object that is only 1 sub object deep, but I've got 2 to three sub object to traverse into. This seems inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to unflatten an object, first create a mapping in reversed direction, that is, flattening. Then, add `ReverseMap()` and you are good to go:

```cs
CreateMap<ResultObject, FlatObject>()
    .ForMember(
        d => d.key1,
        o => o.MapFrom(s => s.category1.sCategory1.key1))
    .ForMember(
        d => d.key2,
        o => o.MapFrom(s => s.category2.sCategory2.key2))
    .ForMember(
        d => d.key3,
        o => o.MapFrom(s => s.category3.sCategory3.key3))
    .ForMember(
        d => d.key4,
        o => o.MapFrom(s => s.category4.sCategory4.key4))
    .ReverseMap();
```