# AutoMapper - Map flatten object to complex object

Tags: c#, automapper

I have these models:

```cs
class Source
{
    String A;
    String B;
    String C;
    String D;
}

class Destination
{
    String A;
    String B;
    Another another;
    Other other;
}

class Other
{
    String C;
    AnotherOne Another;
}

class AnotherOne
{
    String D;
}
```

I want to map the `Source` model to `Destination` and its children.
First approach trying using AutoMapper. So is it possible?
Or is it better to do this assignment manually?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Dotnet AutoMapper Flat schema to complex hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63406924/1838048)

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1: With `ForPath`.**

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, AnotherOne>();
            
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Other>()
        .ForPath(dest => dest.Another, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
            
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
        .ForPath(dest => dest.other, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
});
```

[Demo Solution 1 @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2Jz34y)

---

**Solution 2: With `IncludeMembers` to flatten and `ReverseMap` to create the reverse map explicitly.**

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{           
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, AnotherOne>()
        .ReverseMap();
            
    cfg.CreateMap<Other, Source>()
        .IncludeMembers(src => src.Another)
        .ReverseMap();
            
    cfg.CreateMap<Destination, Source>()
        .IncludeMembers(src => src.other)
        .ReverseMap();
});
```

[Demo Solution 2 @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cdV5uD)

---

**References**

[Flattening (IncludeMembers section) - AutoMapper documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers)

Comment: If the reverse map is not actually needed, of course the first solution is preferable :)